# ImproperlyConfigured at /catalog/borrowed/

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in python-django coding. Currently I am trying to complete the **challenge** on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication but I am facing

**LoanedBooksByAllUserListView is missing the permission_required attribute. Define LoanedBooksByAllUserListView.permission_required, or override LoanedBooksByAllUserListView.get_permission_required().**

In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
    path('authors/', views.AuthorListView.as_view(), name='authors'),
    path('author/<int:pk>', views.AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
    path('mybooks/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name='my-borrowed'),
    path('borrowed/', views.LoanedBooksByAllUserListView.as_view(), name='all-borrowed'),
]
```

In views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre

def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""

    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()

    # Available books (status = 'a')
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()

    # The 'all()' is implied by default.
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()

    # Number of visits to this view, as counted in the session variable.
    num_visits = request.session.get('num_visits', 0)
    request.session['num_visits'] = num_visits + 1

    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
        'num_visits': num_visits,
    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable.
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
from django.views import generic

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 5

class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book

class AuthorListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Author
    paginate_by = 5

class AuthorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Author

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class LoanedBooksByUserListView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.ListView):
    """Generic class-based view listing books on loan to current user."""
    model = BookInstance
    template_name ='catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_user.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BookInstance.objects.filter(borrower=self.request.user).filter(status__exact='o').order_by('due_back')

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class LoanedBooksByAllUserListView(PermissionRequiredMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = BookInstance
    template_name ='catalog/allbookinstancelistborrowed.html'
    paginate_by = 10
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        return BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='o').order_by('due_back')
```

Comment: It's complaining that you didn't put the attribute `permission_required` in `LoanedBooksByAllUserListView `. You added `PermissionRequiredMixin` so it expects that you have `permission_required`

Comment: From the link you shared, have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#views

Comment: So those 2 goes together?  If thats the case where do i add the permission_required? Because from the document it says the world 'or' so i assume use either can already.

Comment: Add it as a class attribute in `LoanedBooksByAllUserListView`. Like `model = BookInstance`

Comment: I got it. Thank you :)